# C sprintf overwrite?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, printf

Can someone explain me why this doesn't work? It appears that the program stops at sprintf(t->tuple[0], "abc"); and I don't know why. Really need help.

```
int testRemoveMeio(){

  int result, i;
  struct list_t *list = list_create();

  char *tdata[3] = {"   ", "2014", "Fixe!"};
  struct tuple_t *t = tuple_create2(3, tdata);
  struct tuple_t *tdups[4];

  struct entry_t *entries[4];

  sprintf(t->tuple[0], "abc");
  tdups[0] = tuple_dup(t);
  entries[0] = entry_create(tdups[0]);
  list_add(list, entries[0]);

  //extra code similar to above
  return 0;
}
```

Edit:

```
struct tuple_t {
    int tuple_dimension; 
    char **tuple;        
};

struct tuple_t *tuple_create2(int tuple_dim, char **tuple){

    struct tuple_t *t = (struct tuple_t *) malloc(sizeof(struct tuple_t));

    if(t == NULL)
        return NULL;

    t->tuple_dimension = tuple_dim;
    t->tuple = tuple;

    return t;
}
```

Edited to add another example from the comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
  char * s = "ABC";
  printf("%s\n",s);
  sprintf(s,"DEF");
  printf("%s\n",s); 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't given us complete working code, but anyway you should be able to use a debugger to pinpoint where the crash is, or if there is actually a crash (you say your program "stops" but that's not very precise).

Comment: [Replying to a comment from OP which was later deleted....]  I cannot explain it because I am not a psychic, but a debugger can run on your actual code and tell you precisely where the crash is.  Give it a try and come back if you still can't make sense of it.  At an absolute bare minimum we would then need to see the definition of `tuple_create2()`.

Comment: I understand. I should probably give you the full code but it is too much. Instead can you explain me this simple thing and why it doesn't work?

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int main(void){ 
        char * s = "ABC";
        printf("%s\n",s);
        sprintf(s,"DEF");
        printf("%s\n",s);
        return 0;
    }

Comment: Never use `sprintf` in 2014. Use [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) on some *array* of `char` or on some heap-allocated `char` zone. Or use [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) if your system has it.

Comment: This **could** work. In practice it doesn't because `s` is initialized with `"ABC"` which is a constant string. Generally, the compiler allocates constant strings into a read-only segment of memory. So `s = "ABC"` initializes `s` with the address of a read-only portion of memory. So when you try to copy something into `s` (using  `sprintf(s,"DEF")` or better `strcpy(s, "DEF")`) an error occurs since you try to write a read-only part..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I pasted the code from  your comment into the question.  Both that and your original code are failing for the same reason, I think: you're modifying string literals.

It's sad but true that in C, string literals like `"hello world"` are illegal to modify, yet are assignable to `char*` without const and without a cast.  This makes it easy to screw up, because modifying such a string is undefined behavior, because it may reside in read-only memory in your program.

To fix it, try this:

```
char tdata[3][6] = {"   ", "2014", "Fixe!"};
```

Or in your second example:

```
char s[] = "ABC";
```

This way you are allocating an actual character array with writable storage.  But please, always use `snprintf()` and never `sprintf()` because the latter is prone to buffer overruns which can crash your program or worse.

Comment: understood. But the problem is this piece of code I gave you was given by the teacher to test our own code so this has to work. I tried the second one and it worked so thanks.

Comment: If your teacher gave you `char *tdata[3] = {"   ", "2014", "Fixe!"};` and told you to modify the strings, you need to first copy the strings to a modifiable array in memory.  Or if you just want to replace the strings with other literal strings, stuff like `tdata[0] = "hi"` will work.

Comment: you're right. tdata[0] = "hi" worked but I can NOT touch this code. sorry for the misunderstanding. This a test code for another code I made. I added to the question parts of that code. can you see now what's wrong? or do you need me to add more code? again thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You second example is wrong. You should use [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) (there is no reason to use `sprintf` in 2014; it is old and dangerous, since it may give a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)) on some *array* of `char` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  char buf[64];
  snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "here %s", "ABC");
  printf("%s\n",buf); 
  return 0;
}
```

You could have used some dynamically allocated memory zone (but then, you should know its size), e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
  size_t siz=32;
   char* ptr = malloc(siz);
   if (!ptr) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
   snprintf(ptr, siz, "here %s and two is %d", "ABC", 2);
   printf("%s\n", ptr);
   free (ptr);
   return 0;
}
```

You might use [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) if your system gives it (e.g. on Linux) like

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
  char* ptrzone = NULL;
  asprintf(&ptrzone, "and here %s and one is %d", "ABC", 1);
  printf("%s\n", ptrzone);
  free (ptrzone), ptrzone = NULL;
}
```

In serious programs, you often should use the result of `snprintf`.

Read the documentation of all the functions you are using, so also: [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html), [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html), [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), [free(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html)

You absolutely should read more about [C dynamic memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

You should compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) and learn to use the debugger (`gdb`) and the memory leak detector [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: If your system doesn't have asprintf it's not too difficult to roll your own using `vsnprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

Some important information is missing as the definition to struct tuple_t and the definition of function `tuple_create2`. If the error occurs on `sprintf(t->tuple[0], "abc")` then either `t->tuple` and/or `t->tuple[0]` is not correctly initialized/allocated. This former should be an array of at least 1 for the example (but more probably 3 if we look at `tdata`) strings and the latter to a string buffer (array of char). Check you or provide us the `tuple_create2` function.

The way you use sprintf to copy a string is dangerous. On your example this works but if the string to copy contains the `'%'` character, bad things can happen (`%` is the character used to specify a format in `printf/scanf` family of functions. If you want to stay with `sprinf` use `sprintf(t->tuple[0], "%s", "abc")` but the simpler is `strcpy(t->tuple[0], "abc")`

Since you have now added the definition of tuple_create2, I try to answer.

In C, it is up to you to manage the memory. What do you expect from `tuple_create2` ?. Your code allocates the space for the "header" (i.e. a `struct tuple` containing the dimension and an array of strings) and fills it with `tuple`. The result is a new object which points to the same memory for the data (i.e. the array of strings). This is OK except if you want to modify this array (which seems to be the case). There are 2 things: the array itself (each entry is a pointer to an array of chars - do you want to modify the pointers ?) and the strings (the content of the array of chars). There are several possibilities for this but this depends on you. For instance the function could allocate its own array of pointers and initialize with the existing data:

```
struct tuple_t *tuple_create2(int tuple_dim, char **tuple){

    struct tuple_t *t = (struct tuple_t *) malloc(sizeof(struct tuple_t));

    if(t == NULL)
        return NULL;

    t->tuple_dimension = tuple_dim;
    t->tuple = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * tuple_dim);

    for(i = 0; i < tuple_dim; i++)  // could be replaced by a memcpy
      t->tuple[0] = tuple[0];  

    return t;
}
```

Then you have to be aware that we copied only pointers. So when you want to modify an element either you simply copy the pointer :

```
 t->tuple[0] = "abc";
```

or you allocate a new string if you thing it can be modified and you don't want this. I give you an example with "abc" but this is not relevant because "abc" is a constant string which will not be modified. Anyway here is the code (note the use of `stdrup` which duplicates the string doing a `malloc`)

```
t->tuple[0] = strdup("abc");
```

Comment: struct tuple_t {
 int tuple_dimension;
 char **tuple;        
};

struct tuple_t *tuple_create2(int tuple_dim, char **tuple){

 struct tuple_t *t = (struct tuple_t *) malloc(sizeof(struct tuple_t));

 if(t == NULL)
  return NULL;

 t->tuple_dimension = tuple_dim;
 t->tuple = tuple;

 return t;
}

Comment: I added struct tuple_t and tuple_create2 to the question. Can you figure out what's wrong there?

Comment: @Miguel Mendes, I have updated my answer to take into account your last code.